# Injecting a class with IOptions in the constructor with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac

I am using Autofac as a container that I am using in another console app that uses the same objects as my main web app, and am trying to inject a class that has IOptions inside his constructor, here's how it looks like:

```
 public class Mailer : IMailer
{
    private readonly StmpSettings _stmpSettings;
    public Mailer(IOptions<StmpSettings> stmpSettings)
    {
        _stmpSettings = stmpSettings.Value;
    }
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_stmpSettings.SenderName, _stmpSettings.SenderEmail));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(email));
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = new TextPart("html")
            {
                Text = body
            };
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
                //I am using my own certificate for https. so when trying to connect to google smtp it cannot authenticate the certificate. I used this temp workaround: SecureSocketOptions.Auto.
                //It means that the mail wont be encrypted.
                //https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#SslHandshakeExceptionhttps://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor look for more secure solutions.

                await client.ConnectAsync(_stmpSettings.Server, _stmpSettings.Port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync(_stmpSettings.Username, _stmpSettings.Password);
                await client.SendAsync(message);
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see the constructor is getting some settings from the injected stmpSettings, any idea to how I could inject it with the autofac container?

so far I have

```
builder.RegisterType<Mailer>().As<IMailer>();
```

but I need to include the things that the constructor injects as well.
having a real hard time understanding to how to do it, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may refer to [autofac guide for ASP .NET Core](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) and use the appropriate registration. Maybe, you should also manually register the `IOptions<StmpSettings>`

Comment: Yeah I know that its what I should do but I am having trouble maunally registering IOptions<StmpSettings>

Answer (score 1):

With `Populate` method you can register services to `Autofac` that registered by **.Net Core** services.

Create a method like this

```cs
public static IServiceProvider BuildAutofacServiceProvider(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    containerBuilder.Populate(services);
    var container = containerBuilder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

Change the return type of `ConfigureServices` method to `IServiceProvider`

```cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      //register services
    return services.BuildAutofacServiceProvider();
}
```

Comment: That is an amazing solution Farhad! but I forgot to mention that the Autofac is not within the .net core mvc project, it is another console app that uses the same objects that the one with the startup class is using.